# xlwings - won't write to 'Range'?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm having problems with basic xlwings operation - writing 'Foo' to cell (range). xlwings

- Mac OSX 10.10.1
- xlWings v0.6.4
- Office for Mac 2016

Instructions from support docs:

```
xw.Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
```

What I type:

```
xw.Range('Sheet1', 'A1:C20').value = 100
```

This is what prompt returns:

> >>> wb = xw.Workbook('Workbook1')
>   >>> xw.Range('Sheet1', 'A1:C20').Value = 100
>   >>> _

I turn to my Workbook - nothing is written into any cells. I can, however, confirm that xlWings is successfully imported into Python and that the wb connection is established -> Excel does open a new workbook upon typing the initial connection statement.

How do I go about troubleshooting this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use lowercase properties in Python: `.value`, not `.Value`